# 2x GPIB via USB Adapter

Tags: test-equipment, scpi

I have 2 of the normal Agilent E3646A power supplies and an Agilent
GPIB/USB adapter.

All 3 devices have different GPIB addresses and the two supplies are connected together with a GPIB cable.

However, only the device works which is *directly connected* with the
USB adapter.

I can connect to the other (it says "Remote Control" on the display as
soon as I connect) but as soon as I send an SCPI command (e.g., RST) I
get a timeout.

So, the connection works in principle but the communication not.
Do I need to terminate the GPIB bus somehow?
Can the cable be broken?

Comment: What happens if you swap the positions of the devices, so that the “other” unit is the one which is directly connected?

Comment: Bad GPIB cable, perhaps?

Comment: @BlairFonville: As I said "However, only the device works which is directly connected with the USB adapter." - so clearly I swapped them.

Comment: No, saying that you have two devices in a chain and only the closest one works, does not make it clear that you have tried swapping them. But having now cleared that up, I would certainly agree that you need to try a new cable.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the GPIB cable was broken! Thanks for the ideas.